# How can I add to a python list until a certain condition is met?

Tags: python

I'm trying to program Yathzee in python. I have come quite far, but I'm stuck at the scoring system. Here is the part of the code I have trouble with (the comments are in Dutch, because it's my native language):

```
import random

# yathzee, je mag 2 keer opnieuw gooien

game_over = False
numberused = False
last_throw = False

score = 0
scorelist = []



#while not gameover, loop gameover = True als ronde=5
while not game_over:
    dice = []
    for d in range(5):
        dice.append(random.randint(1, 6))


    def gooien():
        print('you rolled: ', end='')
        for d in dice:
            print(str(d) + ' ', end='')


    def rerollfunction():
        reroll = input('What dice do you want to reroll?')
        reroll = reroll.split()
        for index, ch in enumerate(reroll):
            reroll[index] = int(ch) - 1
        for index in reroll:
            dice[index] = random.randint(1, 6)
    # start ronde


    #gooien functie
    gooien()
    #vraag wil je opnieuw gooien
    print('Do you want to reroll?')
    reroll = int(input('Yes = 0 , No = 1'))

    #ja
    if reroll == 0 :
        #ronde_klaar =  False
        ronde_klaar = False ##this is for further in the code
        #opnieuw gooien functie
        rerollfunction()
        #gooien functie
        gooien()


    #nee
    if reroll == 1 :
        #ronde_klaar True
        ronde_klaar = True ##this is for further in the code


        #dan moet je scoren
        #kiezen tussen bovenste kant of onderste kant kaart
        print('Do you want to use part 2 of the scorelist?')
        kaart = int(input('Yes = 0 , No = 1'))


        #bovenste kant
        if kaart == 1 :
            #keuze tussen 1,2,3,4,5,6,0 zodra een gekozen is voeg toe aan scorenlijst.

            while not nummergebruikt == 6:
                optellen = int(input('Welke cijfers wil je bij elkaar optellen?'))
                nummergebruikt = True
                if optellen not in scorelist:
                    if optellen == 1 :
                        score += dice.count(1) * 1

                    elif optellen == 2 :
                        score += dice.count(2) * 2

                    elif optellen == 3 :
                        score += dice.count(3) * 3

                    elif optellen == 4 :
                        score += dice.count(4) * 4

                    elif optellen == 5 :
                        score += dice.count(5) * 5

                    elif optellen == 6 :
                        score += dice.count(6) * 6

                elif optellen in scorelist:
                #zit keuze in scorelijst
                    #print je hebt dit al gescoord, dit kan je niet scoren + scorenlijst
                    print('you already scored this number, you cant score these numbers!: ' + str(scorelist))
                    print('Choose again')
                    #print kies opnieuw
```

When you get to the question 'Do you want to use part 2 of the scorelist' and the anwser is no, you want to use part 1. But you can only choose one number to score one time. For example, with `optellen = 1` you can't choose 1 again next round because you have already used it.

I have tried to make a scorelist to which I append 'optellen' and if optellen is in the scorelist, it should say that you can't use it. But I don't know why it doesn't work. I have tried to put it in numerous places, but it still doesn't work.

This is my first ever program, so please explain your solution thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've submitted, I only observe scoreList being initialized as an empty list, and then you do checks whether optellen is in scoreList. You are not appending optellen to the scoreList anywhere. It's important we are appending the correct user choice to the scoreList, we need to find somewhere to add this append.

1. The user has just selected the number they would like to score, and we observe they have not selected this choice before.
2. You can write a line of code which would append the user choice to the scoreList.[hint](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Some other things to consider:

You need to determine when to end the game (set the game_over flag to True).

**What will happen when the user has scored using all 6 numbers?** I understand

```
while not nummergebruikt == 6:
```

is meant to indicate while less than 6 numbers have been used. However, you would need to increment this variable after every time the user selects a number to score. A simpler way to check this would be

```
while len(scoreList)<6:
```

As we already want to keep track of what numbers have been scored so far, and using len() lets us see how many numbers have been used.